# Updating values on listbox using dynamic arrays

Tags: vb.net

I am experiencing an unusually problem in changing the values of item quantity on a listbox . My code is able to change the value of the first item's quantity ,but I don't understand why the loop does not change it for the other quantities.

I declared two (dynamic) arrays globally : arrProduct -to hold the quantity of the item and arrProductID -to keep track of what item`s quantity to change, it stores the item ID at the same time as String variable temp-

### Global variables:

```
Dim dailySale As Decimal
Dim stringF As String = "{0,10},{1,83},{2,55}"
Dim stringP As String = "{0,10},{1,25},{2,60}"

Dim arrProductID(100) As Integer
Dim arrProduct(100) As Integer
Dim c As Integer = 0
Dim temp As String = ""
```

### Code:

```
 Private Sub btnEnter_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEnter.Click
    'Adds an item to the checkbox list when making a sale
    Dim ItemID As Integer = txtSalesProductID.Text
    Dim rowNum As Integer = (Group16DataSet1.Product.Rows.Count) - 1

    Dim valid As Boolean = False


    For value As Integer = 0 To rowNum
        If (ItemID = Group16DataSet1.Product.Rows(value).Item(0)) Then
            valid = True

            If (temp.Contains(ItemID.ToString)) Then
                MsgBox("AGAIN")

                For i As Integer = 0 To c - 1
                    If (arrProductID(i) = ItemID) Then
                        productList.Items.RemoveAt(i + 2)
                        arrProduct(i) += 1
                        productList.Items.Add(String.Format(stringP, Group16DataSet1.Product.Rows(i).Item(1).ToString, arrProduct(i), "R " + Group16DataSet1.Product.Rows(i).Item(4).ToString))
                        MsgBox(i)
                    End If
                Next

            Else
                MsgBox("ENTERED ONCE")
                temp = temp + "," + Group16DataSet1.Product.Rows(value).Item(0).ToString

                ReDim arrProductID(100)
                ReDim Preserve arrProductID(c)
                arrProductID(c) = 1

                ReDim arrProduct(100)
                ReDim Preserve arrProduct(c)
                arrProduct(c) = 1

                productList.Items.Add(String.Format(stringP, Group16DataSet1.Product.Rows(value).Item(1).ToString, arrProduct(c), "R " + Group16DataSet1.Product.Rows(value).Item(4).ToString))

                c += 1
            End If
        End If

    Next

    If valid = False Then
        MsgBox("Product not in stock")
    End If

    For i As Integer = 0 To (productList.Items.Count - 1)
        '  ProductList.SetItemChecked(i, True)
    Next
End Sub
```

Thank you for taking the time to read this request. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Stop using arrays and use the List(of T) collection instead.

Comment: If data comes from a db (`Group16DataSet1`) Why copy it to an array or even list.  Research DataBinding

Comment: I am trying to add the item name that the customer wants to buy,but I can try dataGridView as well formating the item description is still a bit messy.Thank you for your advice.